# The HTML & CSS code is not showing the same output in my actual project, that I have fixed in another separate html file

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my output of the Html and CSS file like this (ss#1); I've created this using a separate HTML and CSS file, but when I'm putting it on my actual Html and CSS file it turns out to be like this (ss#2). How can I fix this?

Here is the source code for ss#1

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Swiper demo</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
        />
        <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
        />

        <!-- Demo styles -->
        <style>
          html,
          body {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
          }

          body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }

          html,
          body {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
          }

          body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items:center;
          }

          .swiper {
            width: 200px;
            padding-top: 200px;
            padding-bottom: 0;
          }

          .swiper-slide {
            display: flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content: center;
            border-radius: 15px;
          }
          .swiper-slide img{
            display:flex;
            width: 100%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
        <!-- Swiper -->

        <div class="swiper mySwiper">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img4.JPG" />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img1.JPG" />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img11.jpeg" />
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img7.jpeg" />
            </div> 
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img10.png" />
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Swiper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
        <script>
          var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
            effect: "cards",
            grabCursor: true,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            centeredSlides: true,
            autoplay: {
              delay: 2500,
              disableOnInteraction: false,
            },
            pagination: {
              el: ".swiper-pagination",
              clickable: true,
            },
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

here is the source code for ss#2

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
        />
        <title>Instant Resume Builder</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f5ba79b0f3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <style>
            section{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0.50%;
    padding: 0.50%;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide img{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/logo.png">
            </div>

            <div class="section">
            
            <!-- Swiper -->

            <div class="swiper mySwiper">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img4.JPG" />
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img1.JPG" />
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img11.jpeg" />
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img7.jpeg" />
                </div> 
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src="/Users/megatron/Documents/Project/ResumeBuilder/images/img10.png" />
                </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Swiper JS -->
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

            <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
            <script>
            var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
                effect: "cards",
                grabCursor: true,
                spaceBetween: 30,
                centeredSlides: true,
                autoplay: {
                delay: 2500,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
                },
                pagination: {
                el: ".swiper-pagination",
                clickable: true,
                },
            });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "output" ? what is "Puting it" mean? and what is "actual" `html` and `css` ? this question makes no sense to me...

Comment: Your images are showing 2 completely different things. based on this noone could help  you with your problem, please edit your question with more information (preferably with working code snippets of both situations, this includes removing local images with placeholders the same size so the markup remains the same) when is it working, how does it look like when it is working. where did you test it when working, where did you test it when not working etc.

Comment: @RamondeVries I've tested it in vscode, and it was working for the separate file, but on the project file, the pictures were zoomed and took the whole page for the animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code I think I can help. First of all, before pasting the style code, come to the beginning without any tab space and paste it there. Then after selecting the whole style code, you can adjust it by pressing the tab / shift + tab keys.

Also, as I said at the beginning, if you are using VS code, you can try to install and adjust the Prettier plugin. (Format on save feature must be turned on in settings) This could also be a solution.

Comment: I'm already using the prettier plugin.

Comment: Have you activated the Format on Save feature (from vscode settings)? If yes, just press ctrl+s to save it after pasting the code.